# Return to a function if file was not detected. (Python)

Tags: python

So I made a retrieve if a file was found with this code:

```
try:
with open('Kappa.txt') as file:
    passexcept IOError as e:
print "Unable to open/detect file."
```

That works fine. So before that function the user can enter a path where this txt file is located on his computer. If Kappa.txt was not found in the directory which the user typed in, the retrieve above should return to the Path-entering function so the user can enter another Path but how?

The Path-entering function looks like that:

```
Path = raw_input("blalblablablablablalb")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much point in doing try - except here. You can easily check if file exists and proceed only if that is the case.

```
import os

file_name = raw_input("File name: ")
#  Until the file user enters is existing, keep asking
while not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    file_name = raw_input("File name: ")

#  At this point you are guaranteed to have a valid path
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

---

If for some reason it is very important for you to do it as try-except, **nut this is much worse code, really**:

```
filename = raw_input("File name: ")
file_succesfully_opened = False
while not file_succesfully_opened:
    try:
        file_succesfully_opened = True
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            ...
except IOError as e:
    filename = raw_input("File name: ")
```

Comment: Either I'm dumb or you just didn't understand what I was asking for ^^ The user enters a path and the retrieve should check if the text file was found in the path, if not it should return to the type your path in function.

Answer (score 0):

Do an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        filename = raw_input("File: ")
        with io.open(filename, encoding='utf8') as fd:
            content = fd.read()
        break
    except IOError:
        print("retry!")
```